# Pygame unable to create a function which will make the snake eat the food and also close the game and also increase snake size

Tags: pygame

Pygame unable to create a function which will make the snake eat the food and also close the game.I want to write a funtion which can make the snake eat the food and increase its length.I have made a funtion which has drawn the circle and the rectangle.

```
from random import randrange
import pygame
from pygame import Color, Surface, event, image, key
import random
import math
pygame.init()
icon = pygame.image.load(r"D:\\icon.png")
blue=(0,0,255)
red =(255,0,0)
yellow = (255,255,0)
screen_size = (720,600)
title = 'Snake Game'
vel = 0
vel_1 = 0
x = random.randrange(100,690)
y = randrange(50,550)
x_enemy = random.randrange(100,690)
y_enemy = randrange(50,550)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
caption = pygame.display.set_caption(title)
def snake(surface,color,dim):
    pygame.draw.rect(surface,color,dim)
def food(surface,color,center,radius):
    pygame.draw.circle(surface,color,center,radius)
score = 0              
running = True
while running:
    dim = (x,y,30,30)
    centre = (80,80)  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False   
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            vel = -0.5
            vel_1 = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            vel = 0.5
            vel_1 = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
           vel_1 = -0.5
           vel = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
           vel_1 = 0.5
           vel = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            running = False
    if x >= 690 :
        running = False
    if x <= 0 :
        running = False
    if y >= 570:
        running = False
    if y <= 0 :
        running = False
    x += vel
    y += vel_1                   
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))              
    snake(screen,blue,dim)
    food(screen,red,[x_enemy,y_enemy],7)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should read about [pygame.Rect.colliderect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect). It's about collision so you can use it for snake eating the food.

Arrays(x-axis array and y-axis array), can be used for snake length. (In Python can be used Lists instead of Arrays) In this arrays, every array's element contains one position of square and this position represents square's topleft(x,y). I already drew a sketch about it that might be more expressive.

(the meaning of "durum" is status)
[image: Snake game]